# psycopg2: Insert numpy Array with NaNs into Table

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, numpy-ndarray

The following code works fine to insert multidimensional numpy arrays into a table

```
def adapt_numpy_array(numpy_array):
    return AsIs(numpy_array.tolist())

register_adapter(np.ndarray, adapt_numpy_array)
register_adapter(np.int32, AsIs)
register_adapter(np.int64, AsIs)
register_adapter(np.float64, AsIs)
```

However, in case the array contains NaNs it breaks:

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: FEHLER:  Spalte »nan« existiert nicht
> LINE 2: ...6000.0, 692000.0, 732000.0, 830000.0, 928000.0], [nan, nan, ..

Changing the adapters to

```
def adapt_numpy_array(numpy_array):
    return numpy_array.tolist()

def nan_to_null(f,
        _NULL=psycopg2.extensions.AsIs('NULL'),
        _Float=psycopg2.extensions.Float):
    if not np.isnan(f):
        return _Float
    return _NULL

register_adapter(float, nan_to_null)
```

yields another error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getquoted'

Why does the second code break, psycopg2 should traverse the list and replace every float by either its value or NULL?
How to insert numpy arrays into a SQL table in case NaNs are present?

Comment: 1) Postgres supports 'NaN' for `float` and `numeric` as  `select 'NaN'::float; NaN` per [Numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html). Though you will have to quote the values as shown. 2) The second error seems to be because you are using the adapter on the list as whole instead of the elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to convert the numpy array to a string, and properly represent the NaN values by `NULL`. The formatted string can then by wrapped by an `AsIs` adapter.

```
import numpy as np
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, AsIs

def adapt_numpy_array(numpy_array):
    return AsIs(str(numpy_array.tolist()).replace("nan", "NULL"))

register_adapter(np.ndarray, adapt_numpy_array)
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it does handle any numpy array that I throw it.